# Passing full data from a store in to a view

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I currently have a list that is populated via a store which works fine. When you click on a list item, my controller gets the record of that list item and passes those details to the view that is pushed on to the stack.

Is there a way to push the full data store in to the view that is added so that it can be referenced? (e.g. I have a list of events, and on the page for a specific event I want to reference the store and bring back the time of the next upcoming event after it)

Here is my current function that pushed the individual record to the view:

```
showDetail: function(dataview, index, item, record){

    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'ScheduleDetails',
        data: record.data
    });
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You can use dataview to access the store itself and then either pass that to the view as an object or just create a variable (as I have in the example below) and pass it as a parameter of your push function.

```
showDetail: function(dataview, index, item, record){
//Next event is the item in the record that I wanted to use to reference another record
    var nextevent = dataview.listItems[record.data.nextevent]._record._data;
    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'ScheduleDetails',
        data: record.data,
        nextevent: nextevent
    });
}
```